# Replicating CouchDB with Cloudant fails

Tags: android, couchdb, cloudant

I have a `CouchDB` database and I want to replicate it on an `Android` device using [`Cloudant`](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/replication.md)

So what I am doing is:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        URI uri = null;
        File path = getApplicationContext().getDir(DATASTORE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            uri = new URI("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:XXXX/my_database/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.d("onCreate",e.getMessage());
        }

        DocumentStore ds = null;
        try {
            ds = DocumentStore.getInstance(path);
        } catch (DocumentStoreNotOpenedException e) {
            Log.d("onCreate",e.getMessage());
        }

// Create a replicator that replicates changes from the remote
// database to the local DocumentStore.
        Replicator replicator = ReplicatorBuilder.pull()
                .from(uri)
                .to(ds)
                .addRequestInterceptors(new BasicAuthInterceptor("myUser:myPass"))
                .build();

// Use a CountDownLatch to provide a lightweight way to wait for completion
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Listener listener = new Listener(latch);
        replicator.getEventBus().register(listener);
        replicator.start();
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("onCreate",e.getMessage());
        }
        replicator.getEventBus().unregister(listener);
        if (replicator.getState() != Replicator.State.COMPLETE) {
            Log.d("onCreate","Error replicating FROM remote");// error
            Log.d("onCreate",(listener.errors).toString());// error
        } else {
            Log.d("onCreate",(String.format("Replicated %d documents in %d batches",
                    listener.documentsReplicated, listener.batchesReplicated)));
        }
    }
```

I am getting two errors;

> onCreate: Error replicating FROM remote onCreate:
>
> onCreate:[java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine if the _bulk_get
> endpoint is supported]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you query the _bulk_get end point with curl using the GET method, what is the response?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/cloudant-sync-datastore-core/src/main/java/com/cloudant/sync/internal/mazha/CouchClient.java

Comment: @AlexisCôté sorry I dont know what you mean

Comment: Try to verify manually if the _bulk_get enpoint exists using the same technique with curl. This will give you the response and maybe give you hint on the real problem

Comment: @AlexisCôté ok thanks!